# Add inner border to table cells

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I am trying to add inner border to table cells like this:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">       
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-top: 2px solid green; border-bottom: 2px solid green; border-left: 2px solid green; border-right: 1px solid green;">Mary</td>
        <td style="border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 2px solid red; border-left: 2px solid red; border-right: 2px solid red;">Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I am trying to add spacing to the border so that each cell border can be distinguished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by removing `border-collapse` on the table and setting the `border-spacing` to 0

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: unset;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-top: 2px solid green; border-bottom: 2px solid green; border-left: 2px solid green; border-right: 1px solid green;">Mary</td>
          <td style="border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 2px solid red; border-left: 1px solid red; border-right: 2px solid red;">Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For red color td you can CSS by using nth-child() like I did

```
.table-bordered tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 43px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

this will only affect the red td

Answer (score 0):

You can use box-shadow inset for this purpose, like this

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px green;
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 2px solid red; border-left: 1px solid red; border-right: 2px solid red; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #00e200;">Mary</td>
          <td style="border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 2px solid red; border-left: 1px solid red; border-right: 2px solid red;">Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css pseudo elements :after or :before with position absolute. Here is important that the td has position relative (anything but static really) so the pseudo element is absoulte to it.

```css
table tr td {
  position: relative;
}

.red:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.green:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">       
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="green">Mary</td>
          <td class="red">Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```